# Flutter Firebase TimeStamp

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I wanna show post which created at today , or last week. How can I do this.

this is my firebase data 
[image]

this is my query

```
  Future<List<Post>> getAllPost(Post lastFetched, int fetchLimit) async {
    List<Post> _postList = [];
    if (lastFetched == null) {
      _querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance
          .collection("posts")
          .orderBy("liked", descending: true)
          .limit(fetchLimit)
          .getDocuments();
    } else {
      _querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance
          .collection("posts")
          .orderBy("liked", descending: true)
          .startAfterDocument(lastDocument)
          .limit(fetchLimit)
          .getDocuments();
    }
    if (_querySnapshot.documents.length != 0) {
      lastDocument =
          _querySnapshot.documents[_querySnapshot.documents.length - 1];
    }

    for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in _querySnapshot.documents) {
      Post tekPost = Post.fromMap(documentSnapshot.data);
      _postList.add(tekPost);
    }
    return _postList;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var startfulldate = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(1556062581000));
db.collection('mycollection')
  .where('start_time', '<=', startfulldate)
  .get()
  .then(snapshot => {              
        var jsonvalue: any[] = [];
        snapshot.forEach(docs => {
          jsonvalue.push(docs.data())
           })
             res.send(jsonvalue);
             return;
            }).catch( error => {
                res.status(500).send(error)
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a library call [timeago](https://pub.dev/packages/timeago).

> useful for creating fuzzy timestamps. (e.g. "5 minutes ago")

```
import 'package:timeago/timeago.dart' as timeago;

main() {
   final fifteenAgo = new DateTime.now().subtract(new Duration(minutes: 15));

   print(timeago.format(fifteenAgo)); // 15 minutes ago
   print(timeago.format(fifteenAgo, locale: 'en_short')); // 15m
   print(timeago.format(fifteenAgo, locale: 'es')); // hace 15 minutos
}
```

Comment: but i need configuration in my firebase searchquery. For example if post created 1 day ago getdocument if not dont get.

Comment: Is `fetchLimit` time in milliseconds? for example, today would be 1589986642126